# Retrieve a custom configuration section

Tags: c#, .net

I want to make a library that will be used by either an exe (app.config) or a website (web.config).  If I create a custom configuration section, and load it using

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
CustomSection section = config.Sections.OfType<CustomSection>().FirstOrDefault();
```

it won't run on web site.  It throws a `exePath must be specified when not running inside a stand alone exe.` exception, since it's not an exe.  I can use something like:

```
CustomSection db = (CustomSection )ConfigurationSettings.GetConfig("CustomSection");
```

But that relies on the section being properly named.  Is there a way to get all the sections and iterate through them?

Comment: Assuming you could get all sections, if its not named properly how would you know which one you needed?

Comment: I would use the latest one. Since it is a custom configuration section, it would be a user error to include more than one. I might be able to throw an exception about it, if only I could know what's in the configuration. On a side note, I think if I override a configuration serializer, I have access to all of them. I'm trying that now.